# How to assign user selection to a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, forms, variables

I have a basic HTML form list:

```
<select name="sites" id="sites"> 
<option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option> 
<option value="http://www.bing.com">Bing</option> 
<option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option> 
</select>
```

I want to be able to assign a string to a variable depending on the user section, e.g. if Google is selected the JS var 'link' equals 'abc'. 
I understand how to assign the value to the variable, but not sure on assigning a string of text.

Would this be along the lines of a if statement; 
if sites = 'http://www.google.com' then var link = 'abc'?

Comment: Guys, when you downvote, write a comment!
Jonathan, your question is the basic of HTML/Javascript.
I advise you to look first at google.

Comment: I have been searching Google to find an answer, but nothing is what I am looking for.
Lots on assigning the selected value to the var (like panther's answer below) but nothing on assigning a certain string of text based on the value, e.g. if value 'http://www.google.com' is selected then var = 'abc'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `onchange` event, then it's simply:

```
var select = document.getElementById('sites');
var str;

sites.onchange = function() {
    str = this.value;

    alert(str);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oLz2wkLb/

Comment: Thanks Panther, but its not the value that I want to assign. E.g. If the value 'http://www.bing.com' is selected, then a string of tent is assigned to the var, like 'abc'.

Comment: @Jonathan: what's the relation between 'bing.com' and 'abc'? What is expected var value when you select 'bing.com', 'google.com' and 'yahoo.com'?

Comment: I have just used these as examples.
I need to be able to add a string of text to the end of the selected URL to track the link. This string of text (tracking tag) will be different depending on what is selected.
So for example, if Bing is selected the user will go to http://www.bing.com?cmpid=abc

Comment: @Jonathan: I'd like to improve my answer, but don't know how. I don't see relation between selected option value and expected var string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original question/comments, what you're trying to do is "map" a set of inputs to specific outputs. While `if`/`else` or `switch` could be used, they are not ideal. Branching code with `if` and `switch` in this way leads to duplicated code that can be difficult to understand and maintain.

Here are a couple alternatives.

**Option 1 - Use a JavaScript `Map`**

```
<select id="searchProviders"> 
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option> 
  <option value="http://www.bing.com">Bing</option> 
  <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option> 
</select>
```

```
const map = new Map([
  ["http://www.google.com", "abc"],
  ["http://www.bing.com", "def"],
  ["http://www.yahoo.com", "ghi"]
]);

const searchProviders = document.getElementById("searchProviders");
searchProviders.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  const result = map.get(event.target.value);
})
```

This keeps the *data* isolated from the *logic* and will make things easier to understand and maintain.

**Option 2 - Use HTML `data-` attributes**

```
<select id="searchProviders"> 
  <option value="http://www.google.com" data-link="abc">Google</option> 
  <option value="http://www.bing.com" data-link="def">Bing</option> 
  <option value="http://www.yahoo.com" data-link="ghi">Yahoo</option> 
</select>
```

```
const searchProviders = document.getElementById("searchProviders");
searchProviders.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  const result = event.target.dataset.link;
})
```